# a loop to add a row to a vector in R

Tags: r, loops, vector

I want to get something like:
1 1 1
1 1 1 
1 1 1 
of course 1 is not my value. but just as an example to ask my question.

```
my.vec <- c(1,1,1)
for(i in 1:3){
 my.vec <-  rbind( my.vec , my.vec )}
```

this obviously does not do what I want, it gives many more rows. how can I add a row to my current vector at each iteration of the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `replicate`

```
replicate(3, my.vec)
```

-ouptut

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1
```

---

In the OP's code, we can change it to

```
out <- c()
for(i in 1:3){
 out <-  rbind(out , my.vec )
}
```